# Automatically detect boot disk with grub0.9X

Tags: grub

I have boot loader setup on a USB key, so when I boot with local grub4dos installation, I use:

```
rootnoverify (hd0)
chainloader +1
boot
```

But since I had two disk (usb and internal HDD), how can I detect the name(hd0, sometimes hd1, don't know why) automatically ? I can't just use `find --set-root`, because my usb has 3 partitions, and wasn't booting from one of it.

Any solutions?